# How can I sort one array depending on another array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays stored in an array. They have the same number of values and are aligned:

```
$matrix['label1']
$matrix['label2']
```

I want to apply alphabetical sorting to $matrix['label1'] and move the contents of $matrix['label1'] in the same pattern. Here is an example of input and output.

```
$matrix['label1'] = ['b','c','a']
$matrix['label2'] = [ 1, 2, 3]

asort($matrix['label1'])
// outputs ['a','b','c']
//$matrix['label2'] should now be depending on that [ 3, 1, 2]
```

How can I change my `asort()` call to get this to work?

Comment: Please make a little example from your input and your expected output

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), just pass both subArrays as arguments to it:

```
<?php

    $matrix['label1'] = ['b','c','a'];
    $matrix['label2'] = [ 1, 2, 3];

    array_multisort($matrix['label1'], $matrix['label2']);
    print_r($matrix);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [label1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [label2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: how could I apply this is a collection of arrays?

Comment: @Emanegux What do you mean with this? If you have multiple arrays?

Comment: If I have $matrix['label3'] and $matrix['label4'] and so on and wanted them to be sorted in the same way $matrix['label2'] was sorted

Comment: @Emanegux Just use `call_user_func_array()` and pass all sub-Arrays as arguments by reference, e.g. `call_user_func_array("array_multisort", [&$matrix["label1"], &$matrix["label2"], &$matrix["label3"], ...]);`